# Limit the number of queried items from GeoFire

Tags: android, firebase, geofire

I have a lot of entry in the same location. I would like only to get the 10 latest added items using Geofire. I know that it can be done easily with firebase using Query.limitToLast() but I don't know how to do it with Geofire.

If it is not possible, do you have any workaround that I can apply ?

Comment: looks like there's no such method to limit by number of items in GeoFire, there's only by radius. if you want to get the latest added items, you can use FirebaseQuery to do that in your `items` node, not in the `geofire` node, well it depends on the case.

Answer (score 4):

There is only one solution for this :

you should begin a query with a small radius,

and each time you reach onGeoQueryReady() ("All data has been loaded"), you increase the radius by a small amount of the geoquery with .setRadius(r) until you reach the limit you want

based on this https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/issues/59

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to limit the number of keys from Geofire: it will return all keys that fall into the range you query for.

The only thing I can think of is to not insert items if there is already another item in its vicinity. You're essentially clustering items while writing to the database in that case.

Comment: The problem that the items are messages and they need to be all inserted even if they are at the same place... what I don't care about it is old messages (i don't think that my users will be interested in more than 50 old message)... I discovered that it is not possible to do this with GeoFire and I am trying to find a workaround or a way to this. Unfortunately, I didn't succeed. Do you have other proposition ?

Comment: By workaround: I mean something that involves other things than geofire, for example saving another table to firebase and using it to limit geofire query is it possible ?

Comment: It looks like, the returned values are ordered based the time of creation. If can reverse that order, I will remove the listener when the number of item is equal 50. Is there a way to reverse the order of creation ?