# How to I get the N closest points to a coordinate in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

In firebase, I have a dataset of coordinates and I would like to come up with a way to get the N closest points to the user's current location. I'm hoping to find a solution that involves no front-end filtering and no servers/bots for now.

The solution may or may not involve GeoFire, but it's current api does not cover this use case. It only allows me to get points from a location + a radius, doesn't matter if 1 or 10000 points. I ran a few tests and found that the alphabetical order of it's geoHash is only loosely related to the distance, so I really don't think I can use that (If anyone really understands why, please let me know).

Right now I'm using GeoFire and just growing the search radius until I get the number of points I want, but that's not very efficient.

thanks in advance

Comment: There is currently no way to limit the number of keys that are retrieved from GeoFire, beyond its filtering on range. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38544974/limit-the-number-of-queried-items-from-geofire/38547212#38547212

Comment: I don't think it is an exact duplicate, but they probably do have the same answer. Thanks.